# зачем props в конструктор

Tags: reactjs

```
class Hello extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {welcome: "Добро пожаловать на сайт!"};
        }
        render() {
            return <h1>{this.state.welcome}</h1>;
        }
    }
```

Есть такой класс. Зачем прописывать props в constructor и в super? Ведь если его убрать ничего не сломается.

Answer (score 3):

Вот документация: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

super() - нужен для вызова родительского класса на данном экземпляре, для того чтобы сработало наследование.

в вашем случае constructor вообще не нужен, более того строку

```
this.state = {welcome: "Добро пожаловать на сайт!"};
```

можно поставить на одном уровне с render():

```
state = {welcome: "Добро пожаловать на сайт!"};
render() {...}
```

Вообще в документации написано что конструктор это то место где нужно делать инициализацию состояния (this.state)

В основном раньше я использовал constructor для того чтобы сделать привязку контекста:

```
this.func = this.func.bind(this)
```

Этого можно избежать если пользоваться стрелочными функциями: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 0):

Ничего не сломается до тех пор, пока не попытаться `props` использовать. Они передаются, чтобы были доступны внутри класса. Допишите в рендер `<h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;` и увидите разницу

Comment: ни в одном классе не использую constructor и внутри рендера всегда использую props

Comment: Это потому что по умолчанию props прокидываются в родительский конструктор. А в данном случае, если не передавать props, а конструктор переопределён, props будет неоткуда взять

Comment: не правильно понял вас изначально:)